# Tips for comparing two arrays to get new data

Tags: php, arrays, merge, unique

I am working with various social network's APIs and I am thinking of a way to mimic a real time update.  I know some APIs offer this, but it won't work with the way I am structuring this website.

Just looking for some advice on how to do this by my example below.

When visiting the page the user is grabbing data from 5 different social sites.  Everything 5 minutes the site will recall the functions that grab the data.  Figured I'd do this with jQuery and AJAX.  Each data set from each social site is put into an array.

- Every 5 minutes I get the current arrays for the current data.
- I pass those arrays with AJAX to a getData.php
- getData.php will hold those old arrays.
- getData.php will gather new data from each site, putting into new
  arrays.
- The new data might contain some of the same data from the old array
  so I'll merge the old and new arrays then filter only what's unique
  with array_unique
- Send the new array with only unique data back to AJAX then append to
  the front of the list

I think.  Does that sound right?  Is that completely doable?  Thoughts?  Just trying to wrap my head around all this before I dive deep in the code and figure out it's the wrong way to do it.

Comment: Keep it simple and stupid. The more complication the more trouble...

Comment: Was this complicated?  Or is there a simpler way to do it?

Comment: What I am trying to tell is, keep it simple, your logic looks correct, do not force things further until you get the basic functionality, then you can go fancy... And I wish you success.

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you.  I think I can figure this out.  I'll probably post this up when finished for anyone else looking for help.

Comment: I think most api will have a since (of fromID) parameter, why don't use that? If not the results will have a timestamp which you can use. Except there will be faster solutions i think your array_diff should work. Good luck.

Comment: Bass, with most API's they give you the last ID in which to create a pagination to go further back.  Haven't found anything to reverse it.